# iterating over a numpy array returns only the last item

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, return, trigonometry

I am trying to use a Sine wave function for the navigation.
I have two functions here from my main code which reads:

```
def stop():
    steering = 1024
    throttle = 1024
    return steering, throttle

def case2():
    steering = []
    vector = np.vectorize(np.int)
    time_interval = 5
    samples = 50
    t = np.linspace(0, time_interval, samples)
    time_req = 5.0
    A = 900
    vec_steering = A*np.sin(2*(np.pi)*t/time_req) + 1024
    vec_steering = vector(vec_steering)
    throttle = 1050
    for steering in vec_steering:
        steering, throttle = steering, throttle
    return steering, throttle
```

function `stop()` returns me the stated throttle, steering values but the function `case2()` just returns me: `(1023, 1050)`

My expected sinusoidal output from `'case2()'` function is something like this:

```
(1024, 1050)
(1139, 1050)
(1252, 1050)
(1361, 1050)
(1465, 1050)
(1562, 1050)
(1650, 1050)
(1727, 1050)
(1793, 1050)
(1846, 1050)
(1886, 1050)
(1912, 1050)
(1923, 1050)
(1919, 1050)
(1901, 1050)
(1868, 1050)
(1821, 1050)
(1762, 1050)
(1690, 1050)
(1607, 1050)
(1514, 1050)
(1414, 1050)
(1307, 1050)
(1196, 1050)
(1081, 1050)
(966, 1050)
(851, 1050)
(740, 1050)
(633, 1050)
(533, 1050)
(440, 1050)
(357, 1050)
(285, 1050)
(226, 1050)
(179, 1050)
(146, 1050)
(128, 1050)
(124, 1050)
(135, 1050)
(161, 1050)
(201, 1050)
(254, 1050)
(320, 1050)
(397, 1050)
(485, 1050)
(582, 1050)
(686, 1050)
(795, 1050)
(908, 1050)
(1023, 1050)
```

Can someone please enlighten me where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
steering, throttle = steering, throttle
```

This statement effectively does nothing. It reassigns the variables as they are to themselves.

Also, the for loop evaluates fully before anything is returned, leading to only the last assigned values of `steering` and `throttle` being returned. In this case that would not make a difference, as nothing changes in the loop:

```
for steering in vec_steering:
    steering, throttle = steering, throttle
```

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but I think this behaves more like you'd want to:

```
def case2():
    steering = []
    vector = np.vectorize(np.int)
    time_interval = 5
    samples = 50
    t = np.linspace(0, time_interval, samples)
    time_req = 5.0
    A = 900
    vec_steering = A*np.sin(2*(np.pi)*t/time_req) + 1024
    vec_steering = vector(vec_steering)
    throttle = 1050
    return [(steering, throttle,) for steering in vec_steering]
```

I also don't know if this is a good way of achieving what you want, without knowing what you want to do exactly, but hopefully this helps.

Note however, that this now returns a list of tuples which would not make use of numpys vectorization. You could do this as well:

```
def case2(samples: int = 50,
        time_interval: int = 5,
        time_req: float = 5.0,
        steering_ampl: int = 900,
        throttle_ampl: int = 1050,
        steering_offset: int = 1024):
    
    vector = np.vectorize(np.int)
    t = np.linspace(0, time_interval, samples)
    vec_steering = vector(
        steering_ampl*np.sin(2*(np.pi)*t/time_req) + steering_offset
        )
    throttle_vec = throttle_ampl * np.ones(vec_steering.size,
                             dtype=np.int)
    return np.vstack([throttle_vec, vec_steering])
```

I also moved some constants to be arguments here and included typehints. The `steering` list was also removed as it is not needed.

Finally I cleaned it up a bit. What entails 'clean' can be a bit subjective however. Whether the variable names used in the latter example are an improvement can be a matter of opinion as well to some degree.

Comment: thanks for your time mate.
What I am trying to do here is return a list of steering and throttle values for the robot to follow a sine curve pattern. My throttle values are fixed(constant speed) but steering values keeps changing. *return [(steering, throttle,) for steering in vec_steering]* this line is not returning me anything.
I basically want my output to be expected sinusoidal output as shown above.

Comment: @siddharth No problem at all; I learn as well from answering questions. Are you using micropython?


"return [(steering, throttle,) for steering in vec_steering] 
this line is not returning me anything"

Hmm for me it works. Is there a possibility for you to put all the relevant code in a github repo or something?

I've made a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/jrbergen/2669d84c2e2849d3855d2366f937b7e9) with my exact code.


For me it prints [(1050, 1024), (1050, 1139), ... (stuff left out bc character limit) , (1050, 908), (1050, 1023)]

Answer (score 1):

Your last return statement is outside the for loop so it is returning only one single tuple but if you want all the values then you can store the values that you want to return in a list and then return that list after the loop. Here you are just updating the values of steering and throttle but not storing it anywhere.

Comment: you mean append each element from for loop to the list and return it?

Comment: @siddharth yes. You can simply append in list or you can you can use list comprehension to append the elements and then return it after the loop. Here ans is list
    for steering in vec_steering:
        ans.append((steering,throttle))
    return ans

Comment: thanks it worked but what if i want to unpack this ans as (steering, throttle) and return it?